# Asp.net and Oracle : OracleException

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, odac

I am trying to install my web application to the server. I am using Windows 2012 R2, ASP.NET 4.5, Oracle 11g db server and ODAC121012xcopy_64.

I extracted zip file, called "install.bat all c:\oracle oracle_home" command and "iisreset". Then, my web page show OracleException (0x80004005). I try to change to ODAC11xxxx , ODT11xxx but not work (sometimes the error change to "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" but I use client from the same package).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid Oracle client issues with .net applications, you can use the [managed driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html), it does not require the Oracle client to be installed and won't interfere with it if one is installed.

Migrating the source code to the managed driver from the non managed driver is most of the time just a matter of changing a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answer. I have got the solution.

My solution is change target CPU to x86 and use ODAC112040xcopy 32bit instead 64bit. My web application work well now. Thank you again ^^.